# Limit as n tends to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I want to calculate
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigl( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \Bigr)^{n^2} e^{-2 n}.
$$

I have tried to solve this question. I know that

$$
\Bigl( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \Bigr)^{n^2} \sim e^{2 n}
$$
(i.e. for large $n$ their values are similar) and therefore I thought that the answer is $1$. But the answer is something else. Where am I going wrong?

I also gave it another thought, as the first part tends to ${e^{2n}}$, the second part tends to $0$. As a result, the product should tend to $0$. Unfortunately, I am wrong again.

Comment: The limit of a product equals the product of the limits only when both limits exist. In this case, the left limit does not. I would try a simplification like assuming the limit is $L$, take the log of both sides, and use continuity of the logarithm, which allows the log of the limit is equal to the limit of the log.

Comment: The first part doesn't tends to $e^{2n}$, it tends to $\infty$. The second part does tend to $0$. But then you get an indeterminate form $\infty \times 0$.

Answer (score 3):

By expanding the logarithm, we have
\begin{align*}
(1 + 2 / n)^{n^2}
\;=\;
\exp\Bigl( n^2 \log(1 + 2 / n) \Bigr)
\;&=\;
\exp\Bigl( n^2 \bigl(2 / n - \frac{(2 / n)^{2}}{2} + O(1 / n^3) \bigr) \Bigr)
\\
&=\;
\exp\Bigl( 2 n - 2 + O(1/n)) \Bigr)
\end{align*}
and so the expression tends to $e^{-2}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Basically you cannot use the product rule of limits as the limit of as the limit for $(1 + 2 / n)^{n^2}$ does not exist. Therefore you have to expand it in the way shown above in order to compute the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also find the limit using L'Hospital by setting $x = \frac 1n$ and then considering the limit for $x\to 0$ as follows:

$$\Bigl( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \Bigr)^{n^2} e^{-2 n} \stackrel{x = \frac 1n}{=} \left(1+2x\right)^{\frac 1{x^2}}\cdot e^{-\frac 2x}$$

Now, the logarithm of the expression on the RHS gives

\begin{eqnarray*}\frac 1{x^2}\log(1+2x) - \frac 2x
& = & \frac{\log (1+2x)-2x}{x^2} \\
& \stackrel{L'Hosp}{\sim} & \frac{\frac 2{1+2x}-2}{2x} \\
& = & -\frac 2{1+2x} \\
& \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} & -2
\end{eqnarray*}
So, the limit is $e^{-2}$.